# Earnshaw's Theorem and Plum Pudding

Tags: electrostatics, atoms, history

I'm trying to understand what Thompson's motivation for his Plum-pudding model was. He chose the nucleus to be a sphere of uniform charge because it was mathematically nice, and chose the charge to be positive to circumvent Earnhsaw's theorem. It's this latter part I'm not understanding so much: the divergence $\nabla\cdot E=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}>0$ (for positive test charge), so any point in the atom would have a negative divergence for a negative test charge (electron). This may be a dumb question, but why was it important to sidestep Earnshaw? What is *physically* wrong with having electrons in an atom be unstably configured?

Comment: Atoms can simply not be explained properly with electromagnetic forces alone. It takes both quantum mechanics and electrodynamics to develop a realistic atomic theory that works, at least, for hydrogen. Beyond hydrogen even that is not quite enough and one has to add additional assumptions that are only properly covered by quantum field theory.

Comment: Yes, but I'm interested in what was going on in Thompson's mind; what his motivation was, rather than what we know now in hindsight.

Comment: What went on in Thomson's mind when he proposed it can only be understood by reading Thomson's autobiography and private writings, if he left any on this  topic, which you would have to ask from the science historians. From a scientific point of view we can only know why it didn't work back then (which is the same reason why it doesn't work, today): electrodynamics, on its own, won't produce stable charge distributions of the right kind, a second "force" is needed.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll have to look a little more for his original writings. That's actually how I found out he proposed a sphere of uniform charge because it was mathematically nice to work with, and no physical reasoning at all. All the books explain why his model was wrong, but I wasn't sure if his reasons for thinking it was a good idea was common knowledge among physicists.

Comment: What other physicists thought when they came up with something is of very limited interest to us. A good example would be Schroedinger's three papers that lead him to propose the equation named after him... two of the papers are, in my opinion, a total intellectual mess, at least I haven't been able to make much sense of them, the third one is a stroke of genius, but it basically gives the solution with few hints of how he "guessed" it. A few years later Schroedinger's thinking about QM seems far removed from that moment of unique clarity, again... life is complicated.

Comment: Yes, Schrodinger is another good example. Another one I've wondered about is the Einstein-field equations. I know Einstein had some physical reasoning justifying them, and Hilbert gave an action minimizing argument, but in the text I've read, it's just taken as given after the DG formalism is developed,  but it's still an idea I'd like to see in any case. At any rate, you're probably right in that it's more a matter of historicity than physics. Thanks for your thoughts! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34579/discussion-between-curiousone-and-user153582).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is physically wrong with having electrons in an atom be
>   unstably configured?

Think of it like this. Imagine that you have a theory that describes how the atoms work, and where you use the best of you knowledge of electromagnetism and Newtonian mechanics. SO you place some positively charged points particles and some negatively charged points particles in a volume that represent your atom. So you have a model of an atom, yey! The only problem with your model is that the configuration is unstable. That is, your atom will fall part instantly, because of Earnhsaw's theorem. This is bad.

Let's try to fix it. So you postulate that the point charges are held in place by some force. The problem here is that there is know physical ways of dosing this. Thus, if you insist on you point particles you have to invoke "magic" to keep them stable.

The plum pudding model is (in this setting) a revision of the original model where you create a stable configuration (this is good), but you pay the price that some of you point particles are now tuned into a continuous charge density instead.

Comment: Does Earnshaw's theorem imply matter falls apart instantly? As far as I know, it only says that a collection of point charges can't be held in static equilibrium with only the electrostatic forces between them: so either don't perturb the charges, or perhaps once perturbed, they quickly rearrange themselves in a different unstable position. I think the problem of the atom falling apart instantly is more appropriate for Rutherford's model, where electrons orbit $\implies$ accelerate $\implies$ emits energy $\implies$ unstable

Comment: @user153582 I think you’re right that the direct implication of Earnshaw's theorem is point charges can't be held in static equilibrium. However, this is enough to cause major problems with atom consisting of more than two point particles with the same sign of the charge. These will instantly try to fly apart (by shear repulsion), and the best you can hope to achieves is that your big atom is split into several smaller atoms of "hydrogen type". So clearly (to me) this is not a good model for a stable element. The problems in Rutherford's model is just an extra complication that you also have.